# Java - BitSet to integer

Tags: java, bitset

So taking the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873952/convert-bitset-to-int) with the most upvotes as a base I tried to create a BitSet and set its bits to form the number 478 (111011110) so I did the following:

```
BitSet set = new BitSet();
set.set(0, true);
set.set(1, true);
set.set(2, true);
set.set(3, false);
set.set(4, true);
set.set(5, true);
set.set(6, true);
set.set(7, true);
set.set(8, false);
System.out.println(bitSetToInt(set));
```

with the aid of the following method:

```
public static int bitSetToInt(BitSet bitSet) {
        int bitInteger = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++){
            if (bitSet.get(i)) {
                bitInteger |= (1 << i);
            }
        }
        return bitInteger;
    }
```

So although I was expecting to get 478 back from this call I am getting 247. Can someone explain me what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit 0 is the smallest bit (1<<0). You have turned on bits 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6 and 7. So your number is `011110111`, which is 247.

Comment: right.. I thought of it but when tried it out I forgot the first index 0 so still got the wrong answer. my bad. thanks